# How can I configure the number of slides in Vuescan for batch scanning?

Tags: batch, slides

I am using Vuescan to scan slides in on my Epson Perfection 2450.

The problem is when batch scanning the slides **Vuescan** thinks that I am scanning in 8 slides and not 4. Now when I scan it takes twice as long, I just need to be sure that Vuescan is just going to scan 4 slides, but I can't find anywhere to set it back to the expected 4 slides.

Starting out I got confused. I like **Vuescan** and thought the Professional version would allow me to configure the number of slides. I can't find the setting and I have found nothing in the documentation or online.

Comment: I have found that the [Vuescan book](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=M_aMEYSuxkEC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) alludes to the issue of batch scanning slides (search for "Multi crop") helpfully it mentions that this is a part of Vuescan that needs more work.
I've followed it's suggestion on using the Custom setting to no avail, if only I could set it just scan 4 slides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you place 4 slides in a transparency adapter, enable `Multi Crop` and then Vuescan recognizes (erroneously) that you want to scan 8 slides.
Subsequently it starts scanning all 8 regions where it thinks slides are present.

To only scan the four slides follow these steps:

1. Enable `Batch Scan` in the `Input` tab.
2. Choose `All` in the `Batch Scan` options drop-down menu.
3. Do a preview scan.
4. After that choose `List` instead of `All` in the `Batch Scan` options.
5. Now you have to find out what frame numbers the actual slides have. You can find this by varying the `Frame number` in the `Input` tab and noting the frame numbers that actually select a slide. Let's assume Vuescan recognized your 4 slides under frame #1, #4, #5 and #8.
6. Now in the text box next to the `Batch List` option write down `1,4,5,8`. This directs Vuescan to only scan these frames.

You can find more information on the commands in the [Vuescan manual](http://www.hamrick.com/vuescan/vuescan.pdf), especially on page 57 where the `Batch List` option is explained.

As my scanner is not supported on my OS anymore I don't have Vuescan installed to show screenshots, but these steps + the manual should be enough.

Comment: Having given up three years ago, I've got back into scanning slides and your advice makes sound sense. thanks